# How do I connect to AWS Postgres Aurora database from my PC?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora

There are similar questions but they seem to be about the serverless version or about MySql which is not the setup I have.

So far I have taken the following steps:

- Set a Postgres db up in Aurora and it is active.
- Set it to be publicly accessible.
- Added my IP to the inbound route for the security group for the VPC.
- Used the Endpoint&Port details (literally copied and pasted from the instance rather than the cluster).
- Copied the database name from the configuration tab of the instance
- Copied the master user from the configuration tab of the cluster.

When I attempt to connect to it from my local PC via PGAdmin I get a timeout error!

What could I be missing?  I have used the type PostgresSQL in the Inbound rule type as there does not seem to be an entry for Postgres Aurora - is this correct?  Should I used a different type of inbound connection?

Comment: Double check the security group, and that your ip is what you think it is.

Comment: I don't believe it.  I had a security group which definitely had my IP in it's inbound rules and on a whim I added my IP to the other 4 security groups too ... it now works ... any idea why that would fix it?!?!?!?